# R - Subset a list of matrices by rowname

Tags: r, matrix

I am attempting to subset a list of matrices by their row names.

```
mtx1 <- matrix(data = c(1:12), nrow = 4)
mtx2 <- matrix(data = c(13:24), nrow = 4)

row.names(mtx1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
row.names(mtx2) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

my_list <- c("B", "D")

mtx_list <- list(mtx1, mtx2)
```

So far I have tried

```
sub_mtx_list <- lapply(mtx_list, subset, row.names(mtx_list) %in% my_list)
```

I thought I would get...

```
[[1]]
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
B    2    6   10
D    4    8   12

[[2]]
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
B   14   18   22
D   16   20   24
```

but I receive an empty set of matrices instead...

```
sub_mtx_list
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lapply(mtx_list, function(x) x[row.names(x) %in% my_list,])`

Comment: Read `?subset`, which says "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get what you expect use this code:

```
 lapply(mtx_list,function(x) x[row.names(x)%in%c("B","D"),])
 [[1]]
   [,1] [,2] [,3]    
  B    2    6   10
  D    4    8   12

 [[2]]
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
 B   14   18   22
 D   16   20   24
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `subset`, you can directly use indices:

```
lapply(mtx_list, function(mat)mat[my_list,])
```

which gives you desired output:

```
[[1]]
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
B    2    6   10
D    4    8   12

[[2]]
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
B   14   18   22
D   16   20   24
```